# have 2 of the same Jquery radio toggle be in one prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this:

```
$('input[name="toggle"]').bind('change',function(){
    var showOrHide = ($(this).val() == 1) ? true : false;
    $('.first-toggle').toggle(showOrHide);
 });
 $('input[name="toggle2"]').bind('change',function(){
    var showOrHide = ($(this).val() == 1) ? true : false;
    $('.second-toggle').toggle(showOrHide);
 });
```

Basically I just want one jquery call instead of making two (or multiple) is there an easy way to do this? Should be a simpler way.

I tried to work with the `.parent()`
 but cant seem to avail.
jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jh48cqf9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using common classes instead of incremental classes makes it a lot simpler. Then you can use traverses to look for specific instances

HTML

```
<div class="toggle">Test 1</div>
```

JS:

```
 $(':radio').bind('change', function () { /* use more specific selector than ":radio" that matches main container */
    var showOrHide = ($(this).val() == 1) ? true : false;
    $(this).siblings('.toggle').toggle(showOrHide);
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pgo4vfr1/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: @Riskbreaker would actually be better to wrap label around radios ( for UX), and can use a traverse like `.closest('div').find('.toggle')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common class for the text divs, and a css selector for target the input's names starting as `toggle`.

Then use a sibling selector as `nextAll` to target the text div...

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jh48cqf9/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('input[name*="toggle"]').bind('change',function(){
        var showOrHide = ($(this).val() == 1) ? true : false;
        $(this).nextAll('div.toggle').toggle(showOrHide);
     });                     
});
```

Comment: never tried nextAll but this makes sense! Thank you so much.

Comment: I really like your answer but had to give it to @charlietfl since he first commented... but I will explore more `nextAll` so thank you!

Comment: @Riskbreaker - Not problem at all... Hope you achieve what you're trying to!